Cómo instalar el paquete Rgdal en la ultima versión de Rstudio
No soy experta en R pero he venido trabajando en el desarrollo de mapas. En mi versión de R 4.2.2, instalé el paquete Rgdal de la siguiente forma: install.packages('rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source') y me funcionó perfectamente. Ahora actualicé mi R a la versión 4.4.0 pero al hacer el mismo proceso me genera eel siguiente error:
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgdal'
* removing 'C:/Users/USUARIO/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/rgdal'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/USUARIO/Documents/rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Alguién podría ayudarme.
Intente descargar el código fuente e instalarlo localmente.
Descargue la ultima versión aquí : https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/
Luego establecí el directorio de trabajo donde se descargó y luego instalé usando install.packages('rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
Pero no funciono

La librería {rgdal} fue descontinuada hace meses, es por ello que la información desde CRAN es la sgte:

Package ‘rgdal’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
Archived on 2023-10-16 at the request of the maintainer. Consider
using 'sf' or 'terra' instead.
A summary of the most recent check results can be obtained from the
check results archive.
Please use the canonical form https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rgdal
to link to this page.

Al ser una librería descontinuada, no está mantenida para las últimas versiones de R, por lo que su instalación puede fallar.
Te recomiendo que leas el siguiente artículo. Como TL;DR: las nuevas infraestructuras de las librerías espaciales en R no requieren de rgdal o rgeos, por lo que te recomiendo que te mudes a las nuevas versiones o "nuevos" paquetes (sf/terra) para realizar tus análisis espaciales.

Hola descarga el paquete rgdal desde https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/ y luego coloca dentro de tu directorio de trabajo llamala al paquete desde tu directorio y listo
